# "Relative pronoun and Conjunction"

Tags: verbs, conjunctions, parts-of-speech, relative-pronouns

What are the basic difference between **Relative pronoun** and **conjunction**

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, those are two very different ideas.

A conjunction connects two sentences or clauses or items in a list together. Common conjunctions are "and", "or", and "but". Like, "We will go to the store and we will go to the park", or "He saw it but he still did not believe it." And the "or" between those two examples is another example.

A relative pronoun is a pronoun that introduces a clause that refers back to something mentioned previously in the sentence. "Bob, who is tall, hit is head on the door." "Who" is a relative pronoun that refers back to Bob. Relative pronouns are often words used to introduce questions, like who, when, and where.

I can't think of an example where a conjunction could be used as a relative pronoun or vice versa. If there are examples that just aren't coming to my mind, someone please shout one out.

Comment: I wouldn't call the question function of the wh-words a relative pronoun usage. The term 'interrogative pronoun' is often used here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sorry if my wording was unclear. What I meant to say was that some the same words used as interrogatives are also used as relative pronouns. No, when used as an interrogative, it is not a relative pronoun and vice versa. But the same words are used both ways. Like a word with two definitions.